# Encountering OSError: -202 when adding modules to Arduino Nano ESP32 micropython script

Tags: screenshot, read-eval-print-loop

I need to install some external libraries/modules to use for my Arduino Nano ESP32 micropython project. I know with the Arduino Lab for Micropython editor, you install these modules by using mip.install instead of pip.
Unfortunately, I keep getting this OSError: -202 whenever I try to install a library. For this example, I am installing a library from GitHub and my code is as simple as follows.  `import mip mip.install('https://github.com/alfonsoma75/sdcard_utils/blob/master/sdcard_utils.py')`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPXsz.png)

I keep getting this OSError: -202 Is there anything I am doing wrong?